VirtualSize printing unusually large sizes for process VAS
I'm trying to enumerate all processes and print out the virtual address size of them as provided in the _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. I'm getting values like: 2203412733952 which is unusually large I believe and I can't understand why because I'm using the proper format specifier for size_t.
Heres the _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION struct:
// ensure proper alignment for 64-bit systems
#pragma pack(push, 8) // align structure to 8-byte boundaries

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER WorkingSetPrivateSize; //VISTA
    ULONG HardFaultCount;                //WIN7
    ULONG NumberOfThreadsHighWatermark;  //WIN7
    ULONGLONG CycleTime;                 //WIN7
    LARGE_INTEGER  CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER  UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER  KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    KPRIORITY BasePriority;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    HANDLE InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
    ULONG  HandleCount;
    ULONG  SessionId;
    ULONG_PTR PageDirectoryBase;
    //
    // This part corresponds to VM_COUNTERS_EX.
    // NOTE: *NOT* THE SAME AS VM_COUNTERS!
    //
    SIZE_T PeakVirtualSize;
    SIZE_T VirtualSize;
    ULONG  PageFaultCount;
    SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
    SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
    SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    //
    // This part corresponds to IO_COUNTERS
    //
    LARGE_INTEGER ReadOperationCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER WriteOperationCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER OtherOperationCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER ReadTransferCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER WriteTransferCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER OtherTransferCount;
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION, * PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;

#pragma pack(pop)

// Validate structure size
#ifndef _WIN64
C_ASSERT(sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION) == 0xB8); // Must be 8-byte aligned
#endif

Heres my code:
BOOL enumAllProcesses() {
    fnNtQuerySystemInformation pNtQuerySystemInformation = (fnNtQuerySystemInformation)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"NTDLL.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    if (pNtQuerySystemInformation == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to get NtQuerySystemInformation function address \n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION sysProcessInfo; // buffer
    DWORD dwProcInfoSize;
    unsigned long RetLen;
    NTSTATUS STATUS;

    // first call to NtQuerySystemInformation to get the size needed for all processes
    // not providing any buffer for the process information, which is fine because the goal is to find out how much memory you need to allocate.
    STATUS = pNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, NULL, 0, &dwProcInfoSize);
    if (STATUS != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) {
        printf("First call to NtQuerySystemInformation was not STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH: %d \n", STATUS);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // allocate buffer that can hold process information
    sysProcessInfo = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, (size_t)dwProcInfoSize);
    if (sysProcessInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed (sysProcessInfo) \n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // actual call to NtQuerySystemInformation
    // RetLen will store the total size of the data block that contains information about all processes.
    STATUS = pNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, sysProcessInfo, dwProcInfoSize, &RetLen);
    if (STATUS != 0x0) {
        printf("pNtQuerySystemInformation Failed %ld \n", STATUS);
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sysProcessInfo);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // iterate through the SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structures to extract details about each process.
    do {
        printf("\n------------------------------\n");
        if (sysProcessInfo->ImageName.Buffer != NULL) {
            wprintf(L"Process Name: %s \n", sysProcessInfo->ImageName.Buffer);
        }
        if (sysProcessInfo->UniqueProcessId != NULL) {
            printf("Process ID: %lu \n", (DWORD)(ULONG_PTR)sysProcessInfo->UniqueProcessId);
        }
        printf("Number of Threads: %lu \n", sysProcessInfo->NumberOfThreads);
        printf("Virtual Address Space Size: %zu \n", sysProcessInfo->VirtualSize);
        printf("------------------------------\n");

        // done iterating
        if (sysProcessInfo->NextEntryOffset == 0) {
            break;
        }

        // move to next structure in the buffer
        sysProcessInfo = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)((PUCHAR)sysProcessInfo + sysProcessInfo->NextEntryOffset);
    } while (TRUE);

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sysProcessInfo);

    return TRUE;
}

I want to be able to print the size of the VAS for every process if this is possible, I may be misunderstanding something in Windows idk.

Is Windows SIZE_T actually a true size_t?  What do you get if you cast the value to (unsigned long long) and use %llu for the format specifier?

I still get the same result after doing
printf("Virtual Address Space Size: %llu \n", (unsigned long long)sysProcessInfo->VirtualSize);

@kot123, Unusual values like 2203412733952 sometimes hint to their origin when viewed in hex as 0x201 05A2 2000.  Does that value on a 13-bit boundary imply anything to you?

I suspect the packing alignment is actually 4, not 8.
